# import X509Certificates from resource visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, x509certificate

```
 Dim x509Store As New X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    Dim cert = My.Resources.Facebook_com
    x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed)
    x509Store.Add(cert)
    x509Store.Close()
```

the problem in the **x509Store.Add(cert)** line it show this error **"value of type '1-dimensional array of byte' cannot be converted to system.cryptography.x509certificats.x509certificats2"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you are getting from your resources is a byte array.

You should first convert it to a certificate object.

You can try this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x509Store As New X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    Dim certificateBytes() As Byte = My.Resources.Facebook_com
    Dim certificateObject As New X509Certificate2(certificateBytes)
    x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed)
    x509Store.Add(certificateObject)
    x509Store.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: its worked in amazing way but its ask me for confirming add the certificate to store is there any way to baybas this or even answering yes in programmatically way

Comment: You can try other overloads of .Add method, it may have an overload to suppress this confirmation dialog, because Fiddler2 adds certificates to my personal store and that dialog never came up

Comment: yea i will search thank you and thank you for your time

Comment: hey please look here i found some thing but it give me erorr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741795/install-certification-to-x509store-visualbasic

Comment: You should execute your code with elevated privileges. (Run as admin)